# SQLite.Net OrderBy function returns Null reference exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

#### Platform:

- Windows 8.1 Universal
- [sqlite-net 1.0.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/) *previously see edit below*
- [SQLite.Net PCL 3.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) *current*

#### Working

I had a Table

```
public class CommandData
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    [Column("Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("TimeStamp")]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

#### Breaking change

But, SQLite returns the `DateTime`'s [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) as `Unspecified` and treated as Local; I had to change the table to always return UTC Time (*I also tried DateTime.SpecifyKind(this.TimeStampStore , DateTimeKind.Utc), where TimeStampStore is type DateTime*) :

```
public class CommandData
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    [Column("Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SQLite.Ignore]
    public DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(this.TimeStampStore).ToUniversalTime();
        }
        set
        {
            TimeStampStore = value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s") + "Z";
        }
    }

    [Column("TimeStamp")]
    public string TimeStampStore { get; set; }
}
```

This change broke the following:

```
SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Table<CommandData>().OrderBy(x=>x.TimeStamp)
```

Stack trace:

> at SQLite.TableQuery'1.AddOrderBy[U](Expression'1 orderExpr, Boolean asc)
>
> at SQLite.TableQuery'1.OrderBy[U](Expression'1 orderExpr)

#### Reason

After a bit on investigation, I found that the reason for the System.NullReferenceException is the dot operator on the `Table.FindColumnWithPropertyName(mem.Member.Name)` in `SQLite.cs`

```
 private TableQuery<T> AddOrderBy<U> (Expression<Func<T, U>> orderExpr, bool asc)
 {
     ...
                var q = Clone<T> ();
                if (q._orderBys == null) {
                    q._orderBys = new List<Ordering> ();
                }
                q._orderBys.Add (new Ordering {
                    ColumnName = Table.FindColumnWithPropertyName(mem.Member.Name).Name,
                    Ascending = asc
                });
                return q;
 }

 public Column FindColumnWithPropertyName (string propertyName)
 {
     var exact = Columns.FirstOrDefault (c => c.PropertyName == propertyName);
     return exact;
 }
```

The `propertyName` is "TimeStamp", but

> `Columns[].PropertyName` is "TimeStampStore"
>
> `Columns[].Name` is "TimeStamp"

and and thus `FindColumnWithPropertyName` returns a `null`

#### Probable Fix

If I change SQLite.cs's `AddOrderBy` function:

```
Table.FindColumnWithPropertyName(mem.Member.Name).Name
```

to

```
Table.FindColumn(mem.Member.Name).Name
```

then my code works.

But I would rather guess that I am doing something wrong since this code was written by people with much more experience than me (*especially because I could not find a related post*)

#### Question

Am I doing something wrong with my setup? I can read and write perfectly but this one thing is giving me quite a headache.

Thank you.

### Edit

I implemented my probable fix (changing the function `AddOrderBy`), which solved my issue.

To use [SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL 1.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/) I moved to [SQLite.Net PCL 3.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) and it's generating the exact same issue;

> at SQLite.Net.TableQuery1.AddOrderBy[TValue](Expression1 orderExpr, Boolean asc)
>
> at SQLite.Net.TableQuery1.OrderBy[TValue](Expression1 orderExpr)

But now I'm unable able to apply my previous fix since I'm no longer presented with the .cs files (it's a .dll now).

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be me but I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Barptad the application of the application is quite trivial: get items from the DB that are ordered by the `TimeStamp`. There are multiple ways to get this; the easiest is probably just read them out to anything that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface and use Linq to `OrderBy` them. The application is however not the question, but rather my SQLite implementation that isn't working.

Comment: I have run into similar SQLite and DateTime issues. And as you just said I ended up making a query to select the objects and then just do an OrderBy with Linq on the result. Altough it might be a bit late at this point but I found the SQLiteNetExtensions Nuget package very helpful when I have to deal with SQLite. It is based on slite-net and it comes very handy to set up relations and perform most of the standard operations.

Comment: This could help someone else who arrives here, I hit this issue when using .OrderBy(x=>x.Y) where Y was a valid property but marked [Ignore] so it was not a valid column.